# How do i flush memory in a Python program with C-library?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, memory-leaks, c-libraries

The Python-programs function is to find the brightest light with a webcam and send X,Y-coordinates to a arduino program. This is to follow the sun with a camera.

The the problem is that the memory increases until the program freezes.
I've tried to deleve all the variables after use. But it's still using too much memory.

os: Windows 7

How can I find the leak, and stop it?

Here's the python code:

```
import cv
import traceback
import serial



try:
    cv.NamedWindow("CameraFeed", 1)
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
    cv.NamedWindow("Altered", 1)


except:
    cv.DestroyWindow("CameraFeed")
    cv.DestroyWindow("Altered")
    traceback.print_exc()

ser = serial.Serial("COM15",9600)



def repeat():
    imga = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(imga),8,3)
    cv.Smooth(imga, img, cv.CV_BLUR, 3)     


    thresholded_img =  cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 1)
    del(img)


    minv = cv.Scalar(250,250,250, 0)
    maxv = cv.Scalar(255,255,255, 0)
    cv.InRangeS(imga, minv, maxv, thresholded_img) 
    del(minv)
    del(maxv)        
            #determine the objects  moments and check that the area is large  
            #enough to be our object
    moments = cv.Moments(cv.GetMat(thresholded_img,1), 0) 
    area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0)

            #there can be noise in the video so ignore objects with small areas 


    if(area > 10000):

                #determine the x and y coordinates of the center of the object 
                #we are tracking by dividing the 1, 0 and 0, 1 moments by the area 
            x = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)/area 
            y = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1)/area 
            del(moments)
            del(area)
                #print 'x: ' + str(x) + ' y: ' + str(y) + ' area: ' + str(area) 

                #create an overlay to mark the center of the tracked object 
            overlay = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(imga), 8, 3) 

            cv.Circle(imga, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (255, 0, 0), 20) 
            cv.Add(imga, overlay, imga)
            del(overlay)
                #add the thresholded image back to the img so we can see what was  
                #left after it was applied 
            cv.Merge(thresholded_img, None, None, None, imga)

            print 'X: ',x
            print 'Y: ',y
            print ' '
            if x < 300:
                print "left"    
            if x > 340:
                print "Right"
            if y < 210:
                print "Up"
            if y > 250:
                print "Down"

            ser.write('%03i%03i\r\n'% (int(x),int(y))) 







    else:
            ser.write('%03i%03i\r\n'% (320,240)) 



    cv.ShowImage("CameraFeed", thresholded_img)
    cv.ShowImage("Altered", imga)
    del(imga)
    del(thresholded_img)


try:
    while True:
        repeat()
        if cv.WaitKey(10) == 13:
            break
except:
    cv.DestroyWindow("CameraFeed")
    cv.DestroyWindow("Altered")
    ser.close()
    traceback.print_exc()

cv.DestroyWindow("CameraFeed")
cv.DestroyWindow("Altered")
ser.close()
del(serial)
exit()
```

Comment: cv (openCV) is a C-library for real-time image processing. I`m using it to process the images from the webcam.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug of GetMat -> http://code.opencv.org/issues/1579

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the bug?

Comment: They don't seem to be working in this bug right now. 
For now, I think you'll have to find and fix the bug on the python wrapper code yourself.
If you do it, let me know, cause this bug is annoying me too...

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct ([example how to do it](http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/setup-opencv-for-python/)). It's not necessary to delete the variables; they will all be deleted when `repeat()` returns.

My guess is that there is a bug in the version of OpenCV that you're using. Try a different version. Consider to report the bug if the behavior happens in the latest version but not in an older one.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried to re-install a later version of openCV. But it was the same problem.

I`ve done some research and it seems that I need to release the frame after cv.QueryFrame or else it leaks. but I don`t know how to do that.

Comment: Nope. The documentation says "The returned image should not be released or modified by the user." Your problem is that you create lots of images with `CreateImage` and you never free those. Create the image objects once and then reuse them.

Comment: And you can check the methods that an image has with `println dir(img)`; maybe there is a free/destroy method.

Comment: Now I`ve tried several versions of OpenCv, no difference. The problem is I constantly need new images, so I can`t reuse the image objects. I also checked the image methods, but I could not find anything I could use.